# Signalr does not fire disconnect after IIS stopped

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, signalr

I have an application where there is one server and several clients connected via signalr. The server is an asp.net application hosted in Win 2012R2, IIS 8.5. Lately I found an issue where when I actually stop the  site from the IIS manager clients are not firing disconnected. It keeps sending the keepalive ping to the server although I have stopped it from IIS. But connection fires the disconnect when I recycle the app pool. Is this the normal behavior of signalr or should it fire disconnect from client side when the server is stopped by IIS?

SignalR version - 2.2.1

Comment: How do you stop IIS?

Comment: I do not stop the IIS. I stop the site from the IIS manager by clicking on the site and stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that stopping the site is not a "graceful" way, so SignalR clients are not notified and thus they keep sending keep-alive messages to the server. This is opposed to application pool recycling which allows for process to end gracefully (shutdown period).

Check [this article](https://patdunn.net/2015/05/05/building-a-simple-presence-manager-for-signalr/) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20170308052748/https://patdunn.net/2015/05/05/building-a-simple-presence-manager-for-signalr/)) to see how to implement a mechanism to overcome this issue:

As your SignalR application grows you will find yourself wanting to handle presence management in a more sophisticated manner. By default **SignalR’s own presence management is in-memory. So if your server restarts or you’re operating in a web farm environment it will not be possible to maintain your connections properly**.

> **What makes a good presence management system?**
>
> [...] **Remove zombie connections.** You need to ensure you hook into
>   all disconnection events in order to update your user connections in
>   the database.